# Geb/groovy/jquery clicks wrong element, even after confirming correct Xpath

Tags: jquery, xpath, groovy

Can't copy code because code is on a system not connected to Internet.

I have an experimental  Geb/Groovy project that click various `<td>` elements on a panel.

All of the spec definitions work fine - except the last one.  Invariably, what gets clicked is not the right-most element, but the one immediately to its left.

I even typed the Xpath into Firebug to locate the element, and it is the right one.

I define all of the elements in the Page file like this:

```
functionsTab (wait:true) {$("td"), class: contains("text"), text:"Functions") }  
directoryTab (wait:true) {$("td"), class: contains("text"), text:"Directory") }  
adminTab (wait:true) {$("td"), class: contains("text"), text:"Admin") }   
messagesTab (wait:true) {$("td"), class: contains("text"), text:"Messages") }  


def goFunctions() { waitFor (functionsTab.click() } // works
def goDirectory() { waitFor (directoryTab.click() } // works
def goMessages() { waitFor (messagesTab.click() } // works
def goAdmin() { 
      waitFor (adminTab.click()   // clicks the Messages tab (?!)

      // Just to see what would work, I tried an explicit Xpath, 
      //commenting out the line above.  This Xpath finds the element I want.
      getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(@class, 'MenuItem')]//td[text()='Admin']")).click()

      // the above line also clicks the "Messages" td element
  }
```

In the Spec file, I just call goAdmin().  Note that whatever flaws there are in how I structure the spec, the same structure works fine for the other "pages" above, i.e., Messages, Functions, Directory.  So I don't know why Admin is the odd man out.

```
def "Admin Page" () {
     given: "I go to main page"
           to UserPage
     expect:
           at UserPage  
     when:  "click notification button on pop-up"
           waitFor(60) {
              confirm()
           }
     then: "go to admin page"
         goAdmin()
     then: 
         at AdminPage
}
```

Any ideas?

---

Part of the confusion is due to the "nested-ness" of the tables in the page.

*Here is something I got to work*
          getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class= 'gwt-MenuItem')]//td[text()='Admin']")).click()

I then tried the code above again,

... contains(@class,'MenuItem') 
, and it "worked" in that it went to the right page.  The test ended with the `waitFor` failing anyway, which seems odd, because it found and clicked the element, so why did it time out?

Just for kicks, I commented out those explicit xpath lines and tried the original, clean

```
adminTab.click()
```

and it worked perfectly - clicked the element, no `waitFor` timeout (!).

I made no other code changes.  I'll have to run several tests over and over and see if perhaps there is some timing-related degradation, but otherwise, I'm kind of baffled as to why this is working today and not two days ago.

Comment: This is extremely bizarre, but I have just reproduced the phenomenon, so I can only report that I ran another test using the 
 
    getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div.....")).click()    // worked

Then I commented that out and tried the original code, which had +not+ been working:

    switchDashboardButton.click()  

And now it worked - clicked the element, and no timeouts.

There has to be a rational explanation for this, but it puzzles me.

Answer (score 0):

Your explicate xpath definition doesn't match what you have at the top of your script.

your explicate path says

```
getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(@class, 'MenuItem')]//td[text()='Admin']")).click()
```

what you have at the top:

```
functionsTab (wait:true) {$("td"), class: contains("text"), text:"Functions") }
```

In the top definition you are looking for a td that contains text = "Functions"

In the explicate definition you are looking for a td with text equal to "Admin"

not to mention the other differences between those 2 webElement definitions.